How to read the current effective resolution for the Exoplayer?
I am looking into the Exoplayer and the stream with better resolution scales down when bandwidth is shrinking.
Is there an interface where I can read the real resolution currently used by the Exoplayer?

ExoPlayer has a method to get the video size:
VideoSize videoSize = player.getVideoSize();

The VideoSize instance contains the video width and height.
